# How to import external JS-script to FXML layout?

Tags: java, javascript, javafx-2, javafx, fxml

I have FXML layout and I want to add external JS file (like `src="http://blablabla.org/bla.js"` in HTTP), I've tried following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?language javascript?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
<children>
    <Button id="button" layoutX="126" layoutY="90" text="Click Me!" fx:id="button"
            onAction="changeButtonLabel(event);"/>
    <Label id="label" layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" prefHeight="16" prefWidth="69"
           fx:id="label"/>
</children>

<fx:script source="http://localhost:8080/TestApplication/main_script.js"/>

<stylesheets>
    <String fx:value="hive://localhost:8080/TestApplication/main.css" />
</stylesheets>
</AnchorPane>
```

But FXML returns me following error:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Base location is undefined.
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ScriptElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:1332)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2314)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2131)
at org.hive.browser.BrowserController$2.run(BrowserController.java:65)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Base location is undefined.
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ScriptElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:1314)
... 3 more
Exception in runnable
java.lang.NullPointerException: Children: child node is null: parent = Pane[id=contentPane]
at javafx.scene.Parent$1.onProposedChange(Parent.java:316)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableObservableList.add(VetoableObservableList.java:165)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.add(ObservableListWrapper.java:144)
at org.hive.browser.BrowserController$2$1.run(BrowserController.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:176)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:76)
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is "Base location is undefined". I suggest to add a "@" before the url, and to put the javascript in some path relative to your code e.g. @scripts/main_script.js, where scripts is a directory  just where your Java code is located.